# Does OpsHub migration utility consider project names case sensitive?

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I've downloaded and installed the migration utility V2.0.0.005. I was previously using an older version to migrate source from our on-premise TFS to an online repository. Now, with the new version, an attempt to setup a migration fails during the validation step with the message: "1 project is missing in destination. Please create projects with same name and template in destination and try again."
I note that the project I want to migrate has a name like 'FrED', while the project on the destination end is called 'FRED' (ie: a difference in case of 1 letter). As mentioned, this used to work ok and I'm wondering if this might be the result of a change in the tool? If so, I guess I can rename the online project? Is there a requirement that the project names have the same case?

Comment: Yes. There is a requirement that the project names should match with their case included. It should have been the same in the older version as well. AFAIK, nothing has been done to change that in newer versions of the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The project name is case sensitive. And you can rename the VSO project by following steps:

1. Open your VSO account from Web Portal. (https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/, without project name)
2. Click "Manage Account" button in up right corner.
3. Click "Manage collection security and group membership" link.
4. Click "Overview" panel.
5. Expand the context menu of the project and select "Rename".
   [image]